# Select a row and insert it with different IDs n times

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, cross-join, generate-series

I am trying to come up with a script in Postgres that will select the first row in a table and insert that row `x` number of times back into the same table.

Here is what I have:

```
INSERT INTO campaign (select column_name from campaign)
SELECT x.id from generate_series(50, 500) as x(id);
```

The above obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want a dynamicly choose the column you're inserting into?

Comment: Please define "first row". And elaborate on which columns to select / insert. Just the given `column_name`? Or the whole row except for `id`? Plus, as *always* your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Not necessarily the "first row", just a random row that already exists in the table. I would like to use all of the values for each column name from the randomly selected row. Postgres version is 9.2

Comment: For "each column"? You mean for every column except `id`, for which you want to provide a new value, right?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter correct

Answer (score 3):

Just get the syntax for the [`INSERT` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) right:

```
INSERT INTO campaign (id, column_name)
SELECT g.g, t.column_name
FROM  (SELECT column_name FROM campaign LIMIT 1) t  -- picking arbitrary row
      ,generate_series(50, 500) g(g);               -- 451 times
```

The `CROSS JOIN` to `generate_series()` multiplies each selected row.

Selecting one *arbitrary* row, since the question didn't define "first". There is no natural order in a table. To pick a certain row, add `ORDER BY` and/or `WHERE`.

There is no syntactical shortcut to select ***all columns except the one named "id"***. You have to use the complete row or provide a list of selected columns.

### Automation with dynamic SQL

To get around this, build the query string from catalog tables (or the information schema) and use [**`EXECUTE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in a plpgsql function (or some other procedural language). Only using [**pg_attribute**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-attribute.html).
[`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) requires Postgres **9.1 or later**.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_multiply_row(_tbl regclass
                                        , _idname text
                                        , _minid int
                                        , _maxid int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN

   EXECUTE (
      SELECT format('INSERT INTO %1$s (%2$I, %3$s)
                     SELECT g.g, %3$s
                     FROM  (SELECT * FROM %1$s LIMIT 1) t
                           ,generate_series($1, $2) g(g)'
                   , _tbl
                   , _idname
                   , string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ')
                   )
      FROM   pg_attribute 
      WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
      AND    attname <> _idname  -- exclude id column
      AND    NOT attisdropped    -- no dropped (dead) columns
      AND    attnum > 0          -- no system columns
      )
   USING _minid, _maxid;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call in your case:

```
SELECT f_multiply_row('campaign', 'id', 50, 500);
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b402f/1)

#### Major points

- Properly escape identifiers to avoid SQL injection. Using `format()` and `regclass` for the table name. Details:

  - [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- `_idname` is the column name to exclude ('id' in your case). Case sensitive!
- Pass *values* in the `USING` clause. `$1` and `$2` in `generate_series($1, $2)` reference those parameters (not the function parameters).

More explanation in related answers. Try a search:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[plpgsql]+[dynamic-sql]+format+pg_attribute

Comment: I am getting the error of `Error : ERROR:  function format(unknown, regclass, text, text) does not exist`

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: I added a fiddle to demonstrate it works in pg 9.3. Also tested with pg 9.2, same result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b402f/1

Comment: This is how I am using the function... https://gist.github.com/dennismonsewicz/ebba6d714b551b803a28

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: That's odd. Your code and call look just fine. Seems like [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/functions-string.html) isn't installed in your system. Are you sure you are running pg 9.2? What do you get with `SELECT version()`?

Comment: this is what I get: `psql (9.2.8, server 9.0.18)
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 9.0.
         Some psql features might not work.`

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: `psql` is just the default command line interface. You are running Postgres 9.0. `format()` was introduced with 9.1. Consider upgrading to a more current version. Or do the string concatenation without `format()` ...

Comment: Then you may be connecting to the wrong database cluster. Get your installation sorted out before you do *anything* else. Remember, [`psql`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/psql/info) is just the command line interface. You want a new version of Postgres.

Comment: How would that function look without using the `format` method?

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: I am not very fond of questions not providing the version information up front. And back-patching to outdated versions is of limited use to the general public. I'll leave that to you. It's not that complicated, though. Start by reading [the manual about `format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to understand what it does.

Comment: Fair enough... Thanks!